# При отправке url страницы в redux, я получаю актуальный url со 2 раза

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Всем привет. Столкнулся c проблемой. Есть задача, нужно при клике на определенный Link (react-router-dom) получить url данной страницы куда перешел и записать этот путь в redux, например /home,  я использовал => useLocation. Проблема заключается в том, что в redux попадает со второго клика на Link, когда жму первый раз на Link, получаю в state '/' а после второго клика на тот же Link уже получаю актуальный url страницы. Если явно указать в dispatch тот же самый '/home', то проблем нет, сразу в redux вижу, но если отправляю pathname из useLocation() то не с первого раза. Я подозреваю, что сначала я отправляю url который еще не сформировался, а только после отправляю актуальный.

1 - мой redux

```
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  activeLink: '',
}

const mainSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'main',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setAddActiveTarget(state, action) {
      state.activeTarget = action.payload;
    },
  },
});


export const { setAddActiveTarget} = mainSlice.actions;

export default mainSlice.reducer;
```

2 - Принимаю в свой компонент и создаю функцию которая принимает в себя url страницы

```
import {memo } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {setAddActiveTarget} from '../store/reducer/main/slice';
import { selectMain } from '../store/reducer/main/selector';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const Navbar = memo(function Navbar({types}) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { activeLink } = useSelector(selectMain);
  let { pathname } = useLocation();


  const onActiveTarget = (url) => {
    dispatch(setAddActiveLink(url));
  };
```

3 - Далее просто в верстке Link

```
  <Link
      to="/home"
      onClick={() => onActiveTarget(pathname)}>
   </Link>
```

Comment: Побольше кода бы выложить

Comment: Добавил по больше

Comment: мое предположение, что в истории этот url еще не появился. Со второго захода он диспатчит

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. При клике на Link я переходил на определенную страницу, так вот когда я переходил на страницу к примеру /home в компоненте Home я уже делал dispatch в useEffect, соответственно я получал уже актуальный url страницы после того как компонент был смонтирован.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setAddActiveLink(pathname));
  }, [pathname]);
```